# Improving question on championship privilege

Tags: discussion, editing, closed-questions, deleted-questions

Re [When does/do a champion/s 'defend' vs start from scratch? Difference between 'champion' and '(recurring) tournament winner'?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/28315/when-does-do-a-champion-s-defend-vs-start-from-scratch-difference-between-ch)

I mean for whatever sport championships there are tennis, boxing, basketball, pro-wrestling or any sport sometimes champions will get full privilege, partial privilege and no privilege.

2 questions:

1. How does any federation of any game decide which of the 3 privileges a champion gets?
2. Sometimes tournaments are called championships. Sometimes tournaments have privilege for the previous tournament winner/championship. What is the point of calling a tournament a championship if the champion doesn't have any privilege?

**Question for this meta post**: How do you suggest I go about asking the above?

Guess re my question #1: I believe this is on-topic. I believe the cases vary by boxing, basketball, tennis and pro-wrestling. In boxing (damn I forgot to mention this), some champions absolutely do get privilege. In basketball, it seems champions don't really get privilege. I just wanna know what's up with that.

Guess re my question #2: I...guess this is on-topic. And if so, then well I thought #2 would be like an easy to follow up to #1 but well guess I'll have to split it?

P.S. Philip Kendall  says

> "Is that always the case in [...] csgo and valorant?" is most definitely asking about e-sports.

Oh drat it's supposed to be 'or' instead of 'and'. I said

> Is that always the case in basketball, csgo and valorant?

I meant

> Is that always the case in basketball, csgo or valorant?

Csgo and valorant are just examples anyway. For this SE site, I don't care what the answer is for csgo or valorant.

Comment: If you are seeking to actually improve the question: start by just asking it, and not speculating and guessing what the answer might be. This would cut out a lot of unnecessary text. Second, get rid of the meta commentary and the off-topic sections. You know they're not on topic, you know they're distracting, and you know they're totally irrelevant to this site, so, exclude them entirely, not by qualification or explanation.

Comment: Related question from board game stack exchange meta. https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2100/improving-question-on-championship-privilege

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, I don't believe there is any way for this question to be on-topic here.

#1 is both:

- Too broad, as you are asking for an answer which encompasses every possible sport.
- Opinion based, because nobody can tell you why a federation made the decision it did.

For the second point, I refer you to [Eric Lippert's great answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323382/525010); while that is for programming language design rather than sport championship design, the same still applies:

> There is no "clean" answer to the question about why the particular sausage was made that way. Design is complex, is iterative, and always is the result of carefully chosen compromises between many competing and incompatible goals.

#2 is a question about English. The "point" is that is how the language has evolved to be used; while there may be an interesting question here about how that evolution has happened, that is off-topic for this site.

Comment: lol ok so AGAIN why don't i just ask 1 post for basketball and then 1 post for soccer/football, 1 post for boxing etc (at least for #1)?

Comment: wait another thing: is it forbidden to ask about comparing sports in general eg why does tennis get to do this while boxing doesn't? It doesn't have to be about championships. It can be about anything. Maybe say doping penalties or whatever.

Comment: Still opinion-based. Read Eric's quote.